# Problem with empty fields iterator when parsing JSON

Tags: json, web-services, jackson

I have this `JSON`: `[{"client":"1"}]`

`JSON` is passed from outside and I have to go and parse the `JSON`, `JSON` can change so I have to read it every time.

Reading online I threw the `Jackson` bookshelf but I've a problem in the output.. fieldsIterator result empty:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(params);

Iterator < Map.Entry < String, JsonNode >> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();

while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
 Map.Entry < String, JsonNode > field = fieldsIterator.next();
 System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
}
```

At the moment It doesn't print anything. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root element is an `array` and for `array` method `fields` returns `empty iterator`. Use `elements`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree("[{\"client\":\"1\"}]");

Iterator<JsonNode> fieldsIterator = rootNode.elements();

while (fieldsIterator.hasNext())
{
    JsonNode field = fieldsIterator.next();
    Iterator<String> elements = field.fieldNames();
    while (elements.hasNext()) {
        String fieldName = elements.next();
        System.out.println("Key: " + fieldName + "\tValue:" + field.get(fieldName).asText());
    }
}
```